# Оформление библиографии

Tags: общие-вопросы, оформление-текста

В списке библиографии можно ли использовать слово "журнал"? Например:
Иванов Д. В. Название статьи в журнале // Журнал "Название журнала" № 1–2 (11–12) 2018. Название изд-ва. С. 43-51.
Или должно быть:
Иванов Д. В. Название статьи в журнале // Название журнала. 2018. № 1–2 (11–12). Название изд-ва. С. 43-51.

Comment: Вроде бы слово "журнал" совсем не по ГОСТу, но автор упорно пишет так. Может быть есть такое правило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, ни разу не видела, чтобы писали слово "журнал".

По ГОСТу:  Лушин С.И. О денежных реформах в России / С.И. Лушин // Финансы. - 2000. - № 5. - С. 25-29.

Коршунова Н.Е. Менеджмент в социальной сфере / Н.Е. Коршунова, О.В. Шатаева // Менеджмент в России и за рубежом. – 2007. - № 6. – С. 66-74.